# Node.js Module Install Not Working

Tags: windows, node.js, module

I have successfully installed node.js(v0.10.29-x86) on my windows machine(32-bit) and able to run 'hello world' program. Now I need 'express' module to be installed. I tried using

```
npm install express
```

and

```
npm install -g express
```

without any success.
I get following error in command line whenever I run my js file.

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
    Error: Cannot find module 'express'

    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\node\test.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Please help.

Comment: What do you get when you run `npm install express`?

Comment: Nitzan, thanks for your time. I just figured out there was path problem. I resolved it by adding full path of express module in my js file. But still do you know in which directory we should install modules?

Comment: They usually install themselves in a dir called "node_modules", you shouldn't have to download any file beforehand.

Comment: @Jake, what path should I give when using 'require'? I mean when I run the command npm install express and in js file I included module by statement require('express'); It was giving cannot found module error.

Comment: Are you running `npm install express` in the same dir your project file is in?  If so you shouldn't have to specify any path.